# EF Hold an entity out of Context and get back when needed

Tags: entity-framework, serialization, objectcontext

I have a Sales Receipt Form which uses EF4.3 ObjectContext. I am struggling to figure out to hold an receipt (an entity in EF ObjectContext) and move out of context and to retrieve back when the user wants it back. The situation is whenever the sales receipt form is closed, the context goes away. And the issue is the user should be able to retrieve it back and add to the current context.

The code to detach

```
Serialize(receipt, savepath)
While Receipt.RECEIPTLINEs.Count > 0
      Context.Detach(Receipt.RECEIPTLINEs.First)
End While
Context.Detach(Receipt)
AddNewReceipt()
```

The code to Attach

```
Dim receipt = DeSerialize(savepath)
Context.Attach(receipt)
```

Comment: Are you using `EntityObject` based entities? In such case give up and load them from database when you need them.

Answer (score 0):

User can always retrieve it back - you will execute a query on the new context. You just need to know identification (key) of the receipt.

If you need to share receipt instance you must simply build some infrastructure code where you will keep reference to receipt and the first form will set it and the later code will use it - that is nothing the EF can do for you. You just need to detach receipt from the context prior to closing the first form.

```
objectContext.Detach(receipt);
```

Comment: Basically you mean I need to have a separate context available globally and whenever user hold a receipt, I have to detach it from the current and attach it to new context. When needed just query the new context and attach it to the current context...

Comment: No. You don't need any global context.

Comment: Thanks for your time. Attach and Detach throws ObjectStateManager error like "cannot track Multiple objects" or "An object with a temporay EntityKey Value cannot be attached to an Object Context". I would really appreciate if you could provide a small code snippet

Comment: I edited my question by adding the code that i use. I am getting error messages.

Comment: If you serialize and deserialize data you don't need to detach them. Also if you use `EntityObject` based entities and you never saved your receipt to context you cannot attach it later on - that is what the exception says. Never saved entities derived from `EntityObject` can only be added by `AddObject` method.